# How does Chrome Storage Sync work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to know if Chrome's Storage.sync could be used for a similar use case:

- A user signs in on computer 1, the extension generates certain amount of data (data1) and saves it to chrome.storage.sync.
- The same user signs in on computer 2, the extension is able to access data1 from chrome.storage.sync, after a while the extension generates additional amount of data (data2) and saves it to chrome.storage.sync
- Now The same user signs in on computer 1, my guess is that storage.sync now contains data2.

But what would happend if he signs in on a new computer? would he receive both data1 and data2?

After playing with storage.sync for a couple of days my guess is that once data has been synchronized once on another computer it gets removed but i can't find anything about it in the docs.